# Error in Azure while trying to create WordPress on App Service : RequestDisallowedByPolicy

Tags: wordpress, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am totally new to Azure and following the Azure Fundamentals course from Coursera.
In an exercise a wordpress website should be created, by firstly activating the sandbox,
and next, being able to use a resource group starting with learn-... which becomes visible after
activation of the sandbox.

Unlike in the tutorial, there is no option to select mySQL in App as a Database Provider while creating the
wordpress-resource, nor is there a mentioning of App Service plan/location or Application Insights.
Maybe some things have changed there over the last months or years, so I tried several other ways to
get the app using the concierge subscription, and different combinations of region, windows versus linux,...
I keep on getting a huge error message including RequestDisallowedByPolicy, 'The template deployment failed
because of policy violation' and other times i get 3 different smaller errors about RequestDisallowedByPolicy:
*(1. Policy: app-service-sku-policy complaining about ASP-learnb113b... (the resource group?) being disallowed by policy, 2. Policy: allowed resource types, complaining about privatelink.mysql.database..., 3. Policy: allowed resource types complaining about privatlink.mysql.database...)*

I am using the signin using Github which is linked to  my Github-account and had no problem activating the sandbox itself.
I tried signing in and out again,
and I tried to create WordPress App Service with MySQL in-app also (using the dropdown in the marketplace), given that according to the course
of Coursera, the database provider should be MySQL in-app. This also gives the same RequestDisallowedByPolicy-error.

Does anyone have an idea about what I can try? Is it obvious from what I tell that I am doing something wrong or
do you think this is probably another kind of problem?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I also have this exact problem. The course seems to be relying on outdated screenshots and directions unfortunately. To me it looks like the Azure portal has changed since they wrote it. I would flag the lesson in their material.

Comment: This is not an answer at all, plz follow the SO policy and do not reply if you don't have any solution, plz just leave a comment.